# Content not fitting in bpopup

Tags: jquery, html, css, bpopup

I am trying to display a form with bpopup, however I can't manage to make the content fit, it particularly looks wrong when resizing the window.
http://www.fundatiacarmengolea.ro, the bpopup is displayed when clicking "Formular de contact".

Answer (score 0):

as i can see, you have not assign width to `#form_div`, and the height is not enough.
P.S: i dont know much about it, but according to my reads, it is not good to use `iframe`, google it more

Comment: The iframe seemed the most easy way to display it nicely, the client specifically sent a picture of "how it should look"

Comment: I am struggling to make it look quite okay, although seems like I will need to do overflow: hidden, which is quite risky when accessing the page on mobile devices